# Protect API with Microprofile JWT without @RolesAllowed annotation

Tags: java, jwt, open-liberty, microprofile

I would like to protect my Rest API with Microprofile JWT.
My app run on OpenLiberty 23.0.0.6 and I'm using mpJWT-1.2 feature.

When I have a group claim in my token and I set a @RolesAllowed annotation on my API, token validation work as expected :

- if there is not token in the request, the request is rejected
- if the token is not valid, the request is rejected
- if the token does not contain the required group, the request is rejected
- otherwise, the request is accepted

So, everything seems correctly configured.

But, I don't want to specify a role on my API because authorization is managed differently and in the real world my token does not have any "group" claim neither one containing a role or similar.

I just want that the application server check (validate) the token for all exposed Rest API.

I've tried to add @LoginConfig annotation on my Application Class as the [documentation](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-jwt-auth-1.2/microprofile-jwt-auth-spec-1.2.html#_marking_a_jax_rs_application_as_requiring_mp_jwt_access_control) says :

> It’s intended usage is to mark a JAX-RS Application as requiring MicroProfile JWT RBAC as shown in the following sample

I was expecting that this will enable by default the verification of a JWT token on all endpoint. But if I do not set @RolesAllowed annotation, nothing happens.

Is it possible to accomplish what I want or Micropfile JWT is really tied to @RolesAllowed annotation and is only triggered if this annotation is present ? The specifications does not seems very clear to me on this point.

Comment: In my understanding, if RolesAllowed is not present, there is no check. The API is open to every caller.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are right but it's weird because I also get an error message from the server before the endpoint is called :
"CWWKS5523E: The MicroProfile JWT feature cannot authenticate the request because the token that is included in the request cannot be validated".

So the application server seems to validate the token before processing the request but it just not throw an exception if the token is invalid...

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Authenticate all OpenLiberty end-points through JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74535181/authenticate-all-openliberty-end-points-through-jwt)

We came to the same conclusion : there is no way to achieve this only with Microprofile JWT.
The best way is to implement a filter to validate the token.

This answer is a good reference to do that : [How to implement REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/how-to-implement-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/26778123#26778123)